# Using Google Geocode API in postman

Tags: google-geocoding-api

I currently dont have a Google API key.For testing purposes, I want to get the latitude and longitude from the zipcode and address.

How do I go about testing this in Postman?

Answer (score 2):

This is a GET request and you can use Postman or curl to hit the API.
Example request:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

See link:
[Google Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start)

Example on Postman:
[image]

Example on curl:
[image]

Comment: The OP has clearly stated that they don't have an API Key, but your answer shows that it is required.